# how Python for loop variable(K) in range(1,11) is used in a word like HHkC and show HH1C,HH2C......HH10C?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables, jupyter-notebook

I ran a for loop for range(1,11) and used k as a variable. but K in HHk_C.txt or HHkC is not interpreted as HH1_C.txt or HH1C rather python read this as HHk_C.txt and HHkC. how can I tell python to read HHk_C.txt or HHkC as HH1_C.txt or HH1C (1 to 10) ?

**CODE**

```
for k in range(1,11):
with open('HHk_C.txt') as f:
    HHkC = f.read().splitlines()
with open('HHk_M.txt') as f:
    HHkM = f.read().splitlines()
with open('HHk_W.txt') as f:
    HHkW = f.read().splitlines()
x[k] = Function(HHkC,HHkM)
y[k] = Function(HHkC,HHkW)
```

**ERROR**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-4574aac9a0b3> in <module>()
      1 for k in range(1,11):
----> 2     with open('HHk_C.txt') as f:
      3         HHkC = f.read().splitlines()
      4     with open('HHk_M.txt') as f:
      5         HHkM = f.read().splitlines()

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HHk_C.txt'
```

Comment: You need to format your line. For example you can try as: `open('HH{}_C.txt'.format(k))` or  `open('HH%i_C.txt' % k)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    with open(f'HH{i}_C.txt') as f:
        #do something
```